# rails autosave nested model selected with where/find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

i have a special case for which i need to know the best practice.

Given a simple has_many association:

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  #provider can be :password, :facebook_oauth etc
  #code is the encrypted password on provider == :password
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications

  #this works
  def encrypted_password=(pw) 
    set = false
    self.authentications.each do |auth|
      if auth.provider.to_sym == :password
        set = true
        auth.code = pw
      end
    end
    self.authentications.build(provider: :password, code: pw) unless set
    pw
  end

  #this only when no password-auth exist yet
  def encrypted_password=(pw) 
    self.authentications.find_or_initialize_by(provider: :password).code = pw
  end
end
```

and then

```
user = User.last
user.password="abcdefg"
user.save
```

While the first solution works, it loads and iterates over ALL associated Authentication objects. It was a workaround but this is a no-go.

The second solution does not work when it loads an existing Password-Authentication object. The User object does not know about the change on the Authentication object loaded with the `find_or_initialize_by` method. The change won't be saved...

Is there a way to register the changed Authentication object back to the User object so that it will be autosaved when called `user.save`?

Comment: Does simply switching to `find_or_create_by` fix your issue?

Comment: No because
a) the issue is not creating new records, the issue is autosaving changed existing records
b) i dont want inconsistent data. when i modify the password through the User object then i want to save it only when i save the User object and only when all validations where run.

Answer (score 1):

It seems saving associating object returned with find back to parent object is impossible as of now.  Refer to this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17466.

I had the same issue, and my workaround was, even though this is not you nor I wanted, to use save in the method yourself and make all the saves inside the transaction.

```
def encrypted_password=(pw)
  self.authentications.find_or_initialize_by(provider: :password).update_attribute(code, pw)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to register the changed Authentication object back to the User object so that it will be autosaved when called user.save?

If your question only consists of needing to know how to save an associated class, you can add this to your class definition:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications, autosave: true
end
```

The `Authentication` object is already referenced back to the `User` object via the `user_id` column that should be on `Authentication` by way of the `belongs_to` method. This `autosave: true` will save the associated object `Authentication` when the parent object (`User`) is saved.

Comment: I tested it and it does not work. I think because of the way i am selecting the Authentication object (`self.authentications.find_by...`) the found and returned record is not hooked back in the `self.authentications` array in the User object and therefore the User object does not know about the changes i made on his child